# Plotting elements from list of matrices in R

Tags: r, list, plot

I have a `list` of `20,000` entries. Each entry is a `25x3` matrix.

I need to generate a plot where `x=1,...,20000` and `y = list[x][1,3]` (this sintaxis doesn't work).

I don't want to iterate through the whole list and save the values in a new vector because I don't want to waste memory if not necessary.

In summary, I need to get the same entry of every matrix that is inside a list, and plot those values.

BETAJ is the list of matrices. I tried the following [image]

What I'm expecting to get, is the value at position [1,3] from the matrices at position 1 through 10,000.

Comment: Do you need to rbind i.e. `do.call(rbind, lst1)`

Comment: How does that work? what is rbind?

Comment: I don't know as there was no reproducible example and expected, it was just a guess. `rbind` is a function

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't put an example because I'm getting errors.. Check my edit pls

Comment: You cannot use `[[` for subsetting more than 1 element.  You need `BETAJ[1:10000]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, be careful how you subset your list.  `list[1]` returns a list containing only the first matrix from your larger list.  You want to use `list[[x]][1,3]` to return the matrix itself.

However, passing this as the y-value in the `plot()` function will not work as x is not defined.  To fix this, I would recommend using `sapply()` to iterate over your list of matrices and retrieve the values you want for plotting.  It would look something like this:

`plot(1:20000, sapply(1:20000, function(x) list[[x]][1,3]))`

I am not quite sure what the memory footprint of using an apply function in-line like this is, but at the very least, it should be less than the footprint of the larger list itself, since it is a very, very small subset of it.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'm looking for!